# how to detect whether browser supports outset border style

Tags: javascript, html, css, border

I'm trying to figure out what browsers are capable of producing button-like boxes (via the outset property). This is the code I have and I tested it in IE7 (which doesn't support outset) and Opera 11 (which supports outset). Upon running this script, the message that appears is "outset" in both environments. How can I make it so that I can get a different value if outset is not supported because clearly from IE7's test, the box is solid and not outset as the message box indicated.

Is there anyway to detect this?

This is my code:

```
<div ID="X">Test</div>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("X");
x.style.width='200px';
x.style.height='200px';
x.style.border='2px solid #FF0';
x.style.border='2px outset #000';
alert(x.style.borderStyle);
</script>
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that IE7 doesn't support outset(even IE5 should support it), the result is simply different(choose another borderColor,e.g. white, and you'll see that it's supported)

Comment: That comment is the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need modernize JavaScript library

Answer (score 0):

mike,you can follow the below plugin for iE

http://css3pie.com/demos/border-radius/